# Where is QGIS Server Tutorial?

Tags: references, qgis-server

I'm looking to get QGIS Server working on a Mac with El Capitan OS.  When I try to access this link:

*http://www.qgis.org/wiki/QGIS_Server_Tutorial*

it gets forwarded to this link:

*https://issues.qgis.org/projects/qgis/wiki/QGIS_Server_Tutorial*

So I created an account for the QGIS issues tracker, but I still can't access the file. I get error "403. You are not authorized to access this page"

Can someone help me access the QGIS Server Tutorial or explain what I need to do to get the server working on El Capitan?

Answer (score 1):

I found [QGIS Server Tutorial](http://docs.qtibia.ro/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_ogc/ogc_server_tutorial.html) for testing version which you can use for the time being. Also, I found that the QGIS team prepared recently a [user manual for QGIS 2.14](http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/pdf/en/QGIS-2.14-UserGuide-en.pdf) which includes valuable information and setup for QGIS Server as well as all aspects of QGIS.

There are also other [documentations](http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/index.html) prepared for QGIS 2.14 including user manuals in different languages, tutorials, etc.